# Eigen-matrix of a tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra

Short vision of my question:

Is there such a thing as eigen-matrix of a tensor?

---

Long vision of my question:

I was given

\begin{equation}
    A=\begin{bmatrix}
    2b-a & a-b\\
    2b-2a & 2a-b\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

to find its eigenvalue and eigenvector, and I have found them with standard method.

However, I observed that the first column vector of $A$ is:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2b-a\\
    2b-2a\\
    \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
    -1& 2\\
    -2 & 2\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    a\\
    b
    \end{bmatrix}=\Lambda_1s
\end{equation}

similarly for the second column:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a-b\\
    2a-b\\
    \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
    1& -1\\
    2 & -1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    a\\
    b
    \end{bmatrix}=\Lambda_2s
\end{equation}

I was thinking so hard how to take advantage of it.

The only idea that I came up with: turning $A$ into a product of a tensor and a matrix - combining $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$ $\longrightarrow 
    \Big(
     \begin{bmatrix}
    -1& 2\\
    -2 & 2\\
    \end{bmatrix} , 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1& -1\\
    2 & -1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \Big)
    $ - times a matrix $S=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & a\\
    b & b\\
    \end{bmatrix}$. Since the product is just $A$, so it obviously has a eigenvalue, but I am left wondering if it is possible and meaningful to have a "eigen-matrix" or " eigen-value" for the tensor? In particular, for this tensor any way the eigen-matrix related to the eigen-vector of $A$?

(the only tensor I have learned is from mathematical method for physics many years ago, so if this is a very silly question or I made some silly mistakes, please forgive me!)

Comment: For your general question: since your tensor is the representation of a linear endomorphism of a finite dimensional vector space, there is a natural concept of isomorphism. For your specific matrix: compute its characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @Mindlack thanks for the comment (I had calculated the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$)! would you mind elaborating a bit more about isomorphism (either on comment or answer)?